# How do I get rid of extra commas in a string after changes to the string?

Tags: php, string

I have a string that keeps track of user IDs as a list of followers, it looks like this:

```
 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,... etc..
```

I have two functions, one to add new followers (update the string with a new number):

```
function my_followers_processor() {

    // post author ID
    $author_id  = $_POST['author_id'];
    $author_n   = $_POST['author_n'];

    // current user ID
    $current_id = $_POST['current_id'];

    // get current id followers meta
    $key        = 'followers';
    $single     = 'true';
    $current_f  =   get_user_meta($current_id, $key, $single);

    // update the string to include the new follower
    $new_follow = $current_f . ',' . $author_id;

    // update the users meta
    update_user_meta( $current_id, $key, $new_follow);

    // redifrect when were done
    wp_redirect( site_url() . '/followers/?follow=' . $author_id);

    // end
    die();

}
```

and one to remove followers (update string to remove ID from the list):

```
function my_unfollowers_processor() {

    // post author ID
    $author_id  = $_POST['author_id'];
    $author_n   = $_POST['author_n'];

    // current user ID
    $current_id = $_POST['current_id'];

    // get current id followers meta
    $key        = 'followers';
    $single     = 'true';
    $current_f  =   get_user_meta($current_id, $key, $single);

    // just to make it easier to understand, set an unfriend var
    $unfriend   =   $author_id;

    // update the string to remove follower
    $new_follow =   str_replace($unfriend,'', $current_f);

    // update user meta
    update_user_meta( $current_id, $key, $new_follow);

    // redifrect when were done
    wp_redirect( site_url() . '/followers/?unfollow=' . $unfriend );

    // end
    die();
}
```

After a few add and removes of friends, I end up with a string that looks like something like this:

```
3,,5,,,,,1,,,,
```

I have tried to str_replace the extra comma when I remove a friend, but then when I add a new friend, there is no comma between the last two numbers in the string and then Ive also tried the opposite of adding a comma, but then I end up with two commas together.

What do I need to add to either or both of the functions to clean up those extra commas and maintain a list with a single comma separated value (like the example list at the top)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manipulating followers using string, use array(by [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)ing the followers' string) to add new follower(s) and/or remove existing follower(s). Later, while updating the the new followers' list, use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to join the array elements. So change both of your functions in the following way,

```
function my_followers_processor() {

    // post author ID
    $author_id  = $_POST['author_id'];
    $author_n   = $_POST['author_n'];

    // current user ID
    $current_id = $_POST['current_id'];

    // get current id followers meta
    $key        = 'followers';
    $single     = 'true';
    $followers  =   explode(",", get_user_meta($current_id, $key, $single));

    // append new follower to $current_f array
    $followers[] = $author_id;

    // update the users meta
    update_user_meta( $current_id, $key, implode(",", $followers));

    // redifrect when were done
    wp_redirect( site_url() . '/followers/?follow=' . $author_id);

    // end
    die();
}
```

and

```
function my_unfollowers_processor() {

    // post author ID
    $author_id  = $_POST['author_id'];
    $author_n   = $_POST['author_n'];

    // current user ID
    $current_id = $_POST['current_id'];

    // get current id followers meta
    $key        = 'followers';
    $single     = 'true';
    $followers  =   explode(",", get_user_meta($current_id, $key, $single));

    // remove follower
    if(($k = array_search($author_id, $followers)) !== false) {
        unset($followers[$k]);
    }

    // update user meta
    update_user_meta( $current_id, $key, implode(",", $followers));

    // redifrect when were done
    wp_redirect( site_url() . '/followers/?unfollow=' . $author_id);

    // end
    die();
}
```

Comment: This works, but its not updating the meta with the new values.

Comment: @jon I've updated my answer. Please test your application with the updated code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

After your processing is complete, take the string and use `explode` to break it apart, then rebuild it with the non-empty elements.

```
<?php
$string = "3,,5,,,,,1,,,,";
$elements = explode(",", $string);
$newstring ="";
foreach ($elements as $pos) {
  if ($pos != '') {
    if ($newstring != "") $newstring .= ",";
    $newstring .= $pos;
  }
}
print_r($newstring);
```